# How to get the context from a function of a class that extends Activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I have a class that extends Activity, When I try to access the context from the onCreate() method it gets printed but when I save it in a variable context and try to access it from the `committext()` function as shown below, It prints null. I also tried using "this" and `getBaseContext()` directly from the `committext()` function as it is a part of the same class, I get null pointer exception. Please help me figure out what is going wrong.

```
public class MainKeyboardActionListener  extends Activity implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener, View.OnTouchListener {
    private Context context;
    public static boolean active = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mode_keyboard, false);
        context=getBaseContext();
        System.out.println("contexxtt1"+context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();    
        active = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private static class myHandler extends Handler {
    }
    ;

    public void setInputConnection(InputConnection ic) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int arg0, int[] arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int keyCode) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int keyCode) {
        commitText(String.valueOf(keyCode));
    }

    private void handleException(int keyCode) {
    }

    private void removeHalantMode() {
    }


    private void commitText(String text) {
        if(active==true) {
            System.out.println("contexxtt"+context);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        active = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Context is your Activity, so to refer to it you need this keyword

Comment: @firegloves I have tried using this, doesn't work

Comment: Post stacktrace for the exception

Comment: where are you setting your KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener, View.OnTouchListener on some view? i think onRelease is never executed. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: post mode_keyboard.xml please

Answer (score 0):

Make your `myHandler` class not `static`.